# How can I add a few hyperlinks in the same cell with xlwt?

Tags: python, xlwt

I tried:

```
link = ''
for photo in photo_list:
    link += 'HYPERLINK("' + photo + '"; "Title");\n'
worksheet.write(row, col, xlwt.Formula(link))
```

But it put only first link.

Comment: Can you add a few hyperlinks in the same cell manually in Excel (1) using HYPERLINK formulas? (2) Using the "Insert Hyperlink" functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have search the subject, and really it's imposible to add two or more hyperlinks to one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `worksheet.write(row, col, xlwt.Formula(link))` outside the loop?

```
link = ''
for photo in photo_list:
    link += 'HYPERLINK("' + photo + '"; "Title");\n'

worksheet.write(row, col, xlwt.Formula(link))
```